# Kubernetes: Automatically determine IP Address of another pod/container

Tags: flask, kubernetes, minikube

I'm using [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/) to test out a local Kubernetes scenario.  I have 2 [Python Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) applications named 'frontend.py' and 'interceptor.py'.  Basically I want to do a GET to the frontend application which will then perform a POST to the interceptor application, and receive a response back from the interceptor.  I have this working if I manually find the interceptor application's IP and provide it in my 'frontend.py' script.

My question: **Is there a recommended way to automatically determine the IP address of an application running in one pod's container from an application inside another pod's container?**

I'm wondering if I might not even need to gather the IP in the application themselves if there is some other way to expose the pods' info to each other via the [Kubernetes Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) that I create, but I haven't had any luck yet.

Below are my services, and deployments.

**flask-frontend-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-deployment
  labels:
    app: flask
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flask
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flask
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flask-frontend
        image: alec/flask/frontend:1.0
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        env:
        - name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
          value: dns
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5001
```

**flask-frontend-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: flask
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5001
    targetPort: 5001
```

**flask-interceptor-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: interceptor-deployment
  labels:
    app: flask
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: inter
      role: mid
      tier: middle
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: inter
        role: mid
        tier: middle
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flask-interceptor
        image: alec/flask/interceptor:1.0
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        env:
        - name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
          value: env
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5002
```

**flask-interceptor-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: interceptor-service
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5002
```

**frontend.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    address = 'http://172.17.0.5:5002/' #<--- this is the IP I want to get automatically 
    r = requests.post(address, data="---[Token]---")
    return "Frontend Here. Response from Backend = "+str(r.content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=5001)
```

**interceptor.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

content = ""

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def testPost():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return "Received POST --->>> " + str(request.data)
    else:
        return "Post didnt work"

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    return "Hello from the interceptor!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=5002)
```

Comment: Why do you need the IP address? Kubernetes service discovery based on DNS will give you what you need using `interceptor-service:5002`. Use this as the value for `address`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have the `kube-dns` add-on enabled in `minikube` you should be able to perform DNS-based service discovery. I would say that this is the recommended way of getting hold of the IP addresses of your resources.

To double check that you have `kube-dns` enabled run `minikube addons list`, it should be enabled by default.

The DNS names created for you will default be derived from the `metadata: name` field of your resource(s). Assuming you'll be using the `default` namespace then your Services DNS-names would be:

`interceptor-service.default.svc.cluster.local`

and

`frontend-service.default.svc.cluster.local`

You could use these fully qualified domain-names within your application to reach your Services or use a shorter version e.g. `frontend-service` as-is. This is possible since your Pods `resolv.conf` will be configured to look in `default.svc.cluster.local` when querying for `frontend-service`.

To test this (and noted in the comments), you should now be able to change this line:

`address = 'http://172.17.0.5:5002/'`

to

`address = 'http://interceptor-service:5002/'`

in your Flask app code.

Please see [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) page for more detailed information about DNS for Services and Pods in Kubernetes.

Comment: Well explained, upvoted. Still, the port needs to be specified as well, so it would be `interceptor-service:5002` as mentioned in my comment above. The `default.svc.cluster.local` part is optional here, since both services are in the same namespace.

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas Good point, updated the answer with your input (and comment)!